# Creating a map with object assignment out of range

Tags: python, arrays, object, variable-assignment

I try to create a 2D dynamic array map and assign to each position of the map a object called Point. When I try to create a map using `_create_map()` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "map.py", line 97, in _create_map
    self.mapa[x][y] = Point()
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I tried different solutions but it still doesn't work.

```
class Map():

    latitude = 0
    longitude = 0
    xsize = 0    #in pixel
    ysize = 0    #in pixel
    mapa = [[],[]]

    def __init__(self, longitude, latitude, xs, ys):
        self.latitude = longitude
        self.longitude = latitude
        self.xsize = xs
        self.ysize = ys
        self.mapa = [[0 for x in range(self.xsize)] for y in range(self.ysize)]

    def _create_map(self):
        for y in range(self.ysize):
            for x in range(self.xsize):
                self.mapa[x][y] = Point()
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing your array at the line you are defining it?

Answer (score 1):

You have your x and y dimensions mixed up. If you want to access your nested list as `self.mapa[x][y]`, then you are getting the xth list from `self.mapa`, and getting the yth element from that inner list.

So you need to initialise it as:

```
self.mapa = [[0 for y in range(self.ysize)] for x in range(self.xsize)]
```

or

```
self.mapa = [[0]*self.ysize for x in range(self.xsize)]
```

That is `xsize` lists each of length `ysize`, as opposed to `ysize` lists each of length `xsize`.

Comment: ²Thanks I did the change you propose and I also changed:

    `def _create_map(self):
        for y in range(self.ysize - 1):
            for x in range(self.xsize - 1):
                self.mapa.append(Point())`